# Using vuex-oidc how and where to set `access_token` in axios default headers and keep it in current state

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, openid-connect

In order to access an API a need to add the current JWT token to API client's default headers.
oidcStore module has an API to get `access_token`, it is `oidcAccessToken` getter.

So my question is how can I call this `oidcAccessToken` getter inside `userLoaded` event callback?
Maybe there is a better place to set this header?
Is there an event to handle access_token change?

Thanks!

```
// In my `store/index.js`

export default createStore({
  state: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {
    oidcStore: vuexOidcCreateStoreModule(
      oidcSettings,
      {
        namespaced: true
      },
      {
        userLoaded(user) {
           // set access_token
          axios.defaults.headers.common['Auth-Token'] = ... ;
        },
        userUnloaded() {
           // delete access_token
           axios.defaults.headers.common['Auth-Token'] = null;
        }
      }
    )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the reply of the creator of a library
https://github.com/perarnborg/vuex-oidc/issues/153

the good way to do this is simply use

```
        userLoaded(user) {
           // set access_token
          axios.defaults.headers.common['Auth-Token'] = `Bearer ${user.access_token}`;
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **axios interceptors**.

With interceptors, You can intercept requests or responses before they are handled by `then` or `catch`.
**Check documentation**: https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors

I have implemented it in the following way:
In `main.js` file

```
import axios from 'axios';
import store from './store';

axios.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
    if (store.state.oidcStore.access_token) {
      request.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${store.state.oidcStore.access_token}`;
    }
});
```

*You can replace `Authorization` with `['Auth-Token']` for your code.*

Note:

- Axios interceptor read the state before every axios network call and add Auth
  header to the request.
- By default, the value of `access_token` is `null`. With this solution, you do not have to look for the event and manage a different state variable.
  Just read the value from `oidcStore` state. It is managed by the library itself.

  [Here are the default values of oidcStore state variables in Vue Devtool.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BSjZ.png)

Comment: i suggest to write the default values of oidStore on the body os your answer instead of reference it by link.

Comment: @regisls Thanks for the feedback.. I hope the answer is still clear with the link. I am new to stackoverflow, I have attached the screenshot which is automatically converted to the reference link. Screenshot of actual store value in devtool is more trust worthy rather than just text/json.
Please upvote if the answer helps you in some way or the other.